# Spring Data JPA. How to filter by child collection attribute child collection result only?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

### Technologies:

- java8;
- spring data jpa;
- hibernate5;
- postgresql;

### Stricture:

`user_table{
   id
   ...
}
calendar{
   id
   ...
}
user_calendar_details (
  id                          BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id                     NOT NULL,
  calendar_id                 NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT user_calendar_uk UNIQUE (user_id, calendar_id),
  user_id                     BIGINT REFERENCES user_table (id),
  calendar_id                 BIGINT REFERENCES calendar (id)
);
CREATE TABLE calendar_details (
  id                              BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_calendar_details_id        BIGSERIAL,
  CONSTRAINT user_calendar_det_uk UNIQUE (user_calendar_details_id),
  user_calendar_details_id        BIGINT REFERENCES user_calendar_details (id)
  ...
);`

### Issue:

Requesting calendar info to load entities only for user who requested the data. (`user_id` could be taken from security context)
For each `calendar` core entity should be loaded only one mapping table result `user_calendar_details` and one `calendar_details`.

### Ways to solve:

I'm planning to consider here one of next cases:

### 1 variant

Implementing entity model to use `@OneToMany` mapping in `Calendar` entity where in inner collection we could have set of `UserCalendarDetails` entities. If collection (of `UserCalendarDetails`) loads it should be filtered and contain only one object `UserCalendarDetails` (because of restriction see upper `user_calendar_uk`). In this case I need make two db requests too load `Calendar` and `UserCalendarDetails` in separate way of specify child collection filter by userId in DB request time.

### 2 variant

Try to use hibernate inheritance 

`@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = “user_id”)`

for `user_calendar_details` and entity model mapping should be `@OneToOne` (between `Calendar` and `user_calendar_details`).

### 3 variant

Some ideas with low level db requests using restrictions in joins. It seems most real and effective way to resolve my issue (working on it).

### Questions:

### question to 1 variant

I've investigated this idea, and my conclusion it is impossible, but I could be mistaken. Similar ideas I detected on stackoverflow also, but without positive answer. Please confirm my conclusion or help with idea to resolve this issue (may be example).

### question to 2 variant

I'm not clear if it possible. If it used in const way I would use `@DiscriminatorValue(“myConcreteUserId”)`. But it should be used in dynamic way. And I have no ideas yet, how to. Is any ideas?

### question to 3 variant

How to save calendar entity in cascade way using `@OneToOne` mapping with `user_calendar_details` (Keep in mind: in db for each `calendar` we can have few row in `user_calendar_details`, but loading for the user should have only one each time)?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood ... the data model is as follows :
1 User has one to many relationship to user calendar details ( and this relation is bidirectional, so user calendar details also has a many to one relation to user)

2 user calendar details has many to one relation to calendar  ( and this relation can also bidirectional, so calendar has one to many relationship to user calendar details)

3 user calendar details has one to one relation to calendar details (I think you might consider merging them to one table .. but it depends on the requirements)

Now let's set the domain model the same way , user calendar details will have one to one relation to calendar and one to one relation. To calendar details .... So you can just simply load the user calendar details by the user id ( using criteria or query or a user object constructed with the I'd) and the one to one relations will be eagerly loaded by default (not two queries ... Only one) , hence you will get the related calendar and calendar details objects